# Wordpress: unexpected orderby difference with meta_query vs. meta_key

Tags: database, wordpress, sorting, collation

While looking into a database collation problem, I noticed some rather odd ordering behavior. Based on the actual query, there's a difference in the order by clause which yields different results when using a `meta_query` rather than just a `meta_key` argument.

In my case, I have a dedicated `meta_key` for lastnames just for this purpose.

```
'meta_key' => 'lastname',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

This produces the following order by clause, which works as expected:

```
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

On the other hand, using

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'lastname_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'lastname',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
),
'orderby' => array(
    'lastname_clause' => 'ASC'
)
```

produces

```
ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there something I should change in my query arguments when using a `meta_query`?

Answer (score 0):

`lastname_clause` is not valid. Try this:

```
'meta_key' => 'lastname',
'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value' => 'ASC',
    'title' => 'DESC' // or whatever you want to sort as second
)
```

More about this -> [Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: But it is. See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/